# Change the date of countdown script to universal time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to change the date format of this [countdown jQuery script](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery) from local time to UTC, but it doesn't work after my change. I even asked there but didn't get an answer.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var note = $('#note'),
        ts = new Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),

        $('#countdown').countdown({
            timestamp: ts,
            callback: function(days, hours, minutes, seconds) {
                var message = "";
                message += days + " day" + ", ";
                message += hours + " hour"  + ", ";
                message += minutes + " minutes"  + " & ";
                message += seconds + " seconds" + " <br />";
                message += "time left";         
                note.html(message);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have changed this :

```
ts = new Date(2012, 0, 1),
```

into

```
ts = new Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in this script:

1) `...e.UTC(2012, 0, 1),` should end with `;`

2) `Date.UTC` is not a constructor. Try: `new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1));`

further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC